Adverbial phrase in perfect continuous tenses


It has been raining.
It had been raining.
It will have been raining.


In perfect continuous tenses, is it necessary to add adverbial phrases or not?
Or does it depend on the main verb?
What about my given sentences?
Are all sentences grammatical?

All sentences are grammatically correct and there is no need in grammar to add adverbial modifiers.  Naturally, if you do add a modifier, that can change the meaning.  Modifiers are grammatically optional, but they are sometimes required when you want to express a particular meaning.
(Note  "Does it depend" not "Is it depend".  Depend is a verb, not an adjective)

(Note 2: “Are all sentences grammatical?” is missing a determiner. These, my, three would all work here. As the question is expressed now, iit asks about a universal statement (one involving every sentence in the universe). Omitting articles in particular is a mistake that’s common for learners of English.)
